# TD gets expand at run time

Tags: java, html

table td gets expand if huge data comes? where as I fixed it to 20% of total table width. How should I manage this?

Please find my code as below. Issue is with 3rd td.

```
<style type="text/css">

.Method_SubTable_TD
{
border:solid black 1.0pt;
padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
}
</style>
<br>
<br>
<table width="90%" >
<tr valign="bottom">
<td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="20%">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">Failure in Clicking on link ABC under Main tab</span></p>
 </td>
<td style="background:#ffc7ce;" class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="10%">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:#9c0006">FAILED</span></p>
</td>
 <td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="20%">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:blue"><a><span     style="color:blue;text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-

word">file:/C:/Testing/<wbr>Selenium_Workspace/JSP/<wbr>Project/Results/<wbr>Scr eenshots/FailTC_2016-07-12_<wbr>12-04-38.jpeg</span></a></span></p>
</td>
<td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="10%">
  <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">Test_DestinationsLink</span></p> 
</td>
<td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="10%">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">88</span></p>
</td>
<td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="10%">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color:black">Google Chrome</span></p>
</td> 
<td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="20%">
<p class="show-read-more"><span style="color:black" ></span></p>
 </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You might need to write javascript to do that.

Comment: can you share more code?

Comment: If you fixed it to 20% do you _really_ want to expand it if the content is larger than the available space? If so why did you fix it to 20% in the first place?

Comment: I don't want to change the width because of this scroll come at the end of browser. I don't have an issue if height change.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can set width style to the td

Add **wrap** attribute to td

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" wrap>ABC</td>
    <td width="30%" wrap>24</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PQR</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I set this to width="10%" but at run time its exapnded if arr_result_testresult.get(i) has huge data.

Comment: Add a wrap attribute to td

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone.

Earlier I have applied the wrap-text to span and it does not work. Now I changed it to p tag and its working.

Please find below code

```
p.test {
width: 11em;
word-wrap: break-word;
}

<td class= "Method_SubTable_TD" width="20%">
<p class="test"><span style="color:blue"><a><span style="color:blue;text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;">
file:/C:/Testing/<wbr>Selenium_Workspace/JSP/<wbr>Project/Results/<wbr>Screenshots/FailTC_2016-07-12_<wbr>12-04-38.jpeg</span></a></span></p>
</td>
```